# How to know jvm memory usages: "heap memory" and "off-heap memory"

Tags: java, memory-leaks, off-heap

I want to see the details about "heap memory" and "off-heap memory".
I have used jmap to see the heap memory usages,
and I want to know the "off-heap memory" usages.
I tried to use `pamap pid` command, but only can see the total memory used by the java process. And I want to see more details which are using the off-heap memory.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20058489/is-there-a-way-to-measure-direct-memory-usage-in-java